# git working with images - no conflict?

Tags: git

**DEV A**

places some images on is local `/project/images/`;

```
1- git add .
2- git commit -a -m "added images from my dev machine"
3- git push (to a bare repo)
```

**DESIGNER A**
Finds the images are not ok, and places their own images on their `/project/images/`

```
1- git pull
2- designer places images on /project/images/
3- git add .
4- git commit -a -m "added images from my designer machine"
5- git push (to a bare repo)
```

For some odd reason, images don't get updated on the remote machine, but the bare repo is updated.

And the strange thing (at least on my eyes)  is:

When we do git status, we get something like:

```
modified image1.png 
modified image1.png 
modified image2.png 
modified image2.png
modified image3.png
modified image3.png
```

So, all images seems to be duplicated somehow... on the status.
On the folder itself, only one single version of each remains.

Does anyone could guess from this description what is going on?

Please also note, that the issue is solved after some push, pulls, deletes... at the end, the thing is working and we finally got a conflict (I was happy, the designer looked at my asking: "why the hell are you happy with the conflict). :)

Anyway, the question still remains:
Does anyone could guess from this description what was going on?

Update:
It could have been the case, that the designer didn't make steps 1, and 2, but, switched those, making step 2 first and then 1. I don't thing that could be an issue, still...

Comment: If you do a `ls -a` do you get duplicate files too? Maybe the filenames are encoded differently so there are actually two of each.

Comment: @poke - same encode. Made on the same application, same name. (just changed the size).

Comment: Is the working directory on a FAT filesystem on any of the systems involved? If yes, try running `git config core.ignorecase true` and `git config core.fileMode false` prior to cloning you repositories, to ignore the common issues encounterd by git with FATfs.

Comment: @MEM what TheCodeArtist is basically saying is, Windows file systems are case-insensitive, while Linux and Macs use a case-sensitive file system. Also, this question still requires more details. Are your developers/designers using different branches? Is it possible to see a commit graph? You can remove sensitive information from the logs.

Comment: @TheCodeArtist I'm on Mac OS X and so is the designer. He both did the images, on is own computer. I just happen to grab it from the network and commit it myself.

Comment: @Cupcake We are using the same branches. Commit graph, didn't know that existed. Have to see. :)

Comment: @MEM run `git log --graph --stat` to generate the commit-graph with info on files modified/added with each commit.

Comment: @Cupcake: MacOS can use case-insensitive file systems; I *think* it does so by default.

Comment: End up to be a non issue. Need to investigate further.